# if IE Condition Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have 2 sections of code for IE and other (Chrome, FF).
I am using IE8 and it is STAYING outside `<!--[if IE]>... <![endif]-->`, any function inside ... doesn't work. However, it is GOING inside `<!--[if !IE]><!-->....<!--<![endif]-->`, which I don't expect it goes through. (I also try some more syntax such as `<!-- [if !IE] -->...<!-- [endif] -->` but it seems not ignore!).

I don't know for sure if `<meta>` tags cause the problems.  Please take a look.

```
            <head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <meta content="no-cache; post-check=0; pre-check=0" http-equiv="Cache-Control"/>
                <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma"/>
                <meta content="Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT" http-equiv="Expires"/>

           <!--[if IE]>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".exportExcel").click(function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
                        var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(table.clone()).html(); window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
                        var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                        objExcel.visible = false; 
                         var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; 
                        var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); 
                        objWorksheet.Paste; 
                        objExcel.visible = true;
                    });
                });
                </script>
            <![endif]-->

            <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <script>
            $(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    $(".exportExcel").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $(table).html());
                    e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            );
            </script>
            <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: you didn't mention which jQuery version you are using. If  <1.9, try this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/ if greater you will need to use the migrate plugin : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: The real question is, why on earth would anyone still be using IE8 ?

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: You aren't including jQuery before you start using it (in your example). The `<script src="jquery.js">` tag needs to come before you start using `$` or `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's just JavaScript, then you can check for the browser version and run a different function depending on the browser.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ?
        function(){ /* IE code */ } :
        function(){ /* Non-IE code */ });
</script>
```

Other ways to detect IE:

```
console.log($.browser.msie);
console.log('ActiveXObject' in window);
console.log(!!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE |Trident\/)\d+/));
```

Comment: `$.browser` was removed starting in jQuery 1.9 and should not be used.

Comment: You can always just use `navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'` instead. For those arguing that this won't work on IE11, this is intentional by Microsoft and your non-IE code probably works well in IE11.

Comment: I didn't see that you were using jQuery 1.10 before, see the edit that I described in my previous comment.

Comment: @ Pluto, Thank you very much! It works like a champ. When I test on IE8, it goes to IE code, when I test it on Chrome and FF, it goes to none IE code section.  As your early comment, you have mentioned IE11, I also try to test it on IE11, but it doesn't work, it doesn't go inside IE code section!  How can I get it work in IE11?

Comment: @abcidd It seems like the simplest check would be replacing the conditional expression with `'ActiveXObject' in window`.

Comment: Thank you, Pluto!  I try `$(document).ready(navigator.appName == 'ActiveXObject' in window ?`  Both IE8 and 11 don't go inside IE code section.

Comment: That would just be `$(document).ready('ActiveXObject' in window ?`.

Comment: Wow, it works in both IE8 and IE11.  Thank you, Pluto!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your compatibility mode in IE8, then try. It may only work in standard and quirks modes.

Have you tried adding the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

These are all the tags on our page and it works

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @abcidd did you ever find the solution to this? was it as simple as pluto's comment about not having jquery listed?

Comment: Thank you, ThisClark very much for your help.  I have not tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` .  I would love to test it.

Comment: I just tried it out, it doesn't work.  It seems like ``content="IE=edge"` doesn't work out in my page- it shows blank.  Thank you very much for your help and concerns!

Comment: @abcidd Ok, I'm stumped on this problem. What you have appears like it *should* work but alas you say it does not. Anyhow, it appears you found a javascript solution from Pluto.

Answer (score -1):

IE conditionals are no longer supported in IE, as of 10

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The OP says they are using IE 8.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that.

Comment: Unless you have an answer for IE8, you should probably delete your answer to prevent further downvotes.

Comment: I don't care about the downvotes, and it's still relevant to someone who may come across the question in the future, so I'm gonna leave it

Comment: It just doesn't answer the OP's question in any way.  Though it is a fact, it's irrelevant to the question.  Not what answers are supposed to be.  It might be more appropriate in a comment.